# At what point does an implicit cast happen in a C++ expression?

Tags: c++, standards, operator-precedence, implicit-conversion

This is a very simple question. I noticed that the following, when compiled in MSVS2012, produces the *expected* result of `0x3412` for `val`:

```
unsigned char test[] = { 0x12, 0x34, 0x56, 0x78 };
unsigned char* ch = test;
unsigned int val = *ch | (*(ch+1) << 8);
```

I would have actually expected the dereferenced char pointer `*(ch+1)` on the right to produce a *char* value of `0x34`, which would then be shifted left 8 bits producing `0x00`. It seems that at the point in time the value is dereferenced, it is already stored in a type large enough to contain at least two bytes.

Is this specified in the *C++* standard somewhere? How exactly does this implicit cast happen?

Comment: Actually, a `char` shifted by 8 bits, assuming an 8-bit `char`, would be undefined behaviour if it weren't for the implicit conversion in question. You shouldn't shift something by a number greater than or equal to the number of bits in what you're shifting.

Comment: If it's implicit, then it's not a cast. A cast is an explicit conversion; this is an implicit conversion (specifically, an integral promotion).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is covered under the [draft C++ standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3485.pdf) section `5.8` *Shift operators* paragraph *1* which says:

> [...]The operands shall be of integral or unscoped enumeration type and integral promotions are performed.[...]

and *integral promotions* are covered in section `4.5` *Integral promotions* which in paragraph *1* says:

> A prvalue of an integer type other than bool, char16_t, char32_t, or wchar_t whose integer conversion rank (4.13) is less than the rank of int can be converted to a prvalue of type int if int can represent all the values of the source type; otherwise, the source prvalue can be converted to a prvalue of type unsigned int.

Comment: @8bitcartridge I just put in a link to the draft standard and you can find most of the C and C++ drafts [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/81656/where-do-i-find-the-current-c-or-c-standard-documents).